# Every symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the closed unit ball of a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ - why?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

I have trouble understanding the following proof:

> **Theorem**: Every symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the closed unit ball of a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$
> **Proof:** Given a symmetric convex body $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we define its (so-called) Minkowski functional $$p_K(x) = \inf\{t>0, x\in tK\}$$
> It is clear that $\{p_K(x)\leq 1\} = K$, so it remains to check that $p_K$ is a norm (exercise).

1. In the definition of $p_K(x)$, there is $``x\in tK"$ - what's $tK$? The convex body scaled in all directions by a factor of $t\in\mathbb{R}$? Also what does $p_K(x)$ really mean intuitively?
2. Why is $\{p_K(x)\leq 1\} = K$?
3. To see that $p_K$ is a norm:
   (i) Consider $p_K(x) = 0$. This means $\inf\{t>0, x\in tK\} = 0$. I need to show that $x=0$. This is a little weird, innit? Perhaps the definition of $p_K(x)$ should have been $p_K(x) = \inf\{t\geq0, x\in tK\}$? 
   (ii) To show $p(ax) = |a|p(x), a\in\mathbb{R}$: we must show $\inf\{t>0, ax\in tK\} = |a|\inf\{t>0, x\in tK\}$. Why does this hold? 
   (iii) Lastly we also need to show the triangle-inequality, i.e. $p(x) + p(y) \ge p(x+y), x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm not necessarily interested in a detailed solution (though that would help), some hints or pointers to get me started would suffice too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the definition of $p_K(x)$, $tK = \{tk ; k\in K\}$.
2. Why is $\{p_K(x)\leq 1\} = K$?

First, if $x\in K$ then $x\in 1K$ so $\inf \{t>0 ; x\in tK\} \leqslant 1$, so $p_K(x) \leqslant 1$.

If $x\in \{p_K(x)\leq 1\}$, then there exists $t\leqslant 1$ such that $x\in tK$. So there exists $k\in K$ such that $x = tk = tk + (1-t)0$ and since $K$ is convex, we have that $x\in K$ ($0$ is in $K$ since $K$ is symmetric).

3. To see that $p_K$ is a norm:
   (i) $p_K(x) = 0$ means $\inf\{t>0, x\in tK\} = 0$, which means there exists a sequence $(t_n)$ of positive numbers such that $t_n \rightarrow 0$ and for all $n$, $x\in t_n K$. So for $n$, there exists $k_n \in K$ such that $x = t_n k_n$. As $K$ is compact (finite-dimension), we can extract $k_{\varphi (n)}$ which converges to $k$. Since $t_{\varphi (n)} \rightarrow 0$, we have $x = \lim t_n k = 0$.
   (ii) To show $p(ax) = |a|p(x), a\in\mathbb{R}$: as you said, we must show $\inf\{t>0, ax\in tK\} = |a|\inf\{t>0, x\in tK\}$. It's true because $x\in tK$ also means $ax \in (at)K$. 
   (iii) For the triangle-inequality, remark that if $x = t_x k_x$ and $y= t_y k_y$, then after some work, we get $x+y = (t_x + t_y)k$ for some $k$. So $p_k (x+y) \leqslant t_x + t_y$. Then since this is true for all $t_x$ and $t_y$ such that $x\in t_x K$ and $y\in t_y K$, we can take the inf of the equation and we get the result.

Comment: Would you rather like to say: "there exists a sequence $t_n$  such that $t_n\to 0$ for all $n, x_n \in t_n K$"? Then if $t_n\to 0$, and $x_n\in t_n K$, we can remark that $x_n\to 0$ as well. How does this imply that $x=0$ though? I'm confused.

Comment: Also, can you add some details to the last part? I think you should assume $x = t_x k_x$ and $y = t_yk_y$ instead. $k_x = k_y$ is not required. Also, this will give us $x+y \in (t_x + t_y)K$ (after some work). So, $p_k(x+y) \leq t_x+t_y$. What's next?

Comment: For your first comment, no I meant that $x\in t_n K$ for all $n$. I'm going to edit my post to give the complete answer.

Comment: And for your second comment, when you have $p_k (x+y) \leqslant t_x + t_y$ then as it's true for all $t_x$ and $t_y$ (which verify the property), then you can pass to inf.

Comment: And yes you're right, I should have assume $x = t_x k_x$ and $y = t_y k_y$. I edited.

Comment: By the way, is this choice of norm unique? and where did we use the fact that $K$ is centrally symmetric?

Comment: It's used when I say that $0\in K$ for the second point. For the unique choice, I don't see how we would do differently.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is already an answer on your questions, I will try to explain the intuition behind the minkowski functional.

You can think  of the minkowski functional $ ρ_Α$  (geometrically) as the fraction $ \frac{d(x,0)}{d_x'}$ where $d(x,0)$ is the distance from x to $0$ and $d_x'$ is the distance from $0$, to the "farthest" point of $A$, in the direction of $x$.
See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chPNk.png) for some visual examples.

In the first example: $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a ball of radius $R$ centered at $0$. It turns out that  $ ρ_A(x) = \frac{||x||}{R}$. Notice that     $ d(x,0)=||x||$ and $ d_x' =R$.

In the second example: $A$ is a half plane in $\mathbb R^2$. The distance from $0$ to the farthest point of $A$ in the direction of $x$ is actually infinity (since $A$ is unbounded in that direction) and $ρ_A(x) =0 = \frac{(OM)}{\infty} $. On the other hand, the  distance from $0$ to the farthest point in $A$ in the direction of $y$ is $N'$. So, $ρ_A(y) = \frac{(ON)}{(ON')}= 1/μ $.

Comment: Thank you, this is some great intuition!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. $p_K(x)$ is measuring, roughly speaking, the smallest dilation $t$ for which $x$ sits on the boundary of the convex body. It might help to consider the case where $K=\overline{B(0,1)}$, the closed Euclidean unit ball. We look for the greatest lower bound of $t$ for which $x\in tK$--but this $t$ is precisely the $t$ for which $x$ lies on the sphere of radius $t$. But that radius tells us the distance of $x$ to the origin, so it's in this way scalings of $K$ can give us a notion of norm.
2. If $x\in 1\cdot K$, then $p_K(x)\leq 1$ since $p_K(x)$ is the infimum of $t$ for which $x\in tK$. Thus $K\subset\{x: p_K(x)\leq 1\}$. The reverse inclusion is a little trickier. Suppose $0<p_K(x)\leq 1$. There is a minimizing sequence $t_n\to p_K(x)$ such that $x\in t_nK$ for each $n$. But then $x/t_n\in K$, and since $K$ is closed, we conclude $x/p_K(x)\in K$. Thus $x\in p_K(x)K$, which is a subset of $K$ since $p_K(x)\leq 1$ and $K$ is convex. If $p_K(x)=0$, then it is not hard to see $x=0$ (if one assumed $x\neq 0$ and $x\in (1/n)K$ for all positive integers $n$, then we get $nx\in K$ for all positive integers $n$--this will contradict boundedness of $K$).
3. (i) I already mentioned this case. You'll want to use boundedness of $K$.

   (ii) Just show that, for $a\neq 0$, $\{t>0: ax\in tK\}=\{t>0: x\in (t/|a|)K\} = \{|a|s>0: x\in sK\}$. The infimum of the last set is $|a|p_K(x)$, so the result will follow.

   (iii) If $x\in t_1K$ and $y\in t_2K$, then show that $(x+y)\in (t_1+t_2)K$. It follows $p_K(x+y)\leq t_1+t_2$. Now take infimums over $t_1,t_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "now take infimums over $t_1,t_2$" - can you tell me how?

Comment: For fixed $t_2$, we have $p_K(x+y)-t_2\leq t_1$. Note $t_1$ was an arbitrary scaling for which $x\in t_1 K$. Since $p_K(x)$ is the *greatest* lower bound of such scalings, we have $p_K(x+y)-t_2\leq p_K(x)$. Now rearrange to get $p_K(x+y)-p_K(x)\leq t_2$ and apply the same trick.

Comment: By the way, is this choice of norm unique? and where did we use the fact that $K$ is centrally symmetric?

Comment: Symmetry is used when proving the homogeneity property (since $a$ may be negative). As for uniqueness I'm not sure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional seems to indicate that seminorms can't be uniquely associated with absorbing sets. That being said, I think norms should associate uniquely with convex bodies. If $K$ is convex body, $p$ is as above, and $q$ is another norm on the space with $K=\{q\leq 1\}$, then given $x\neq 0$ the vector $x/q(x)$ should be the unique point in $K$ where the ray $\gamma(s)=sx$ with $s\geq 0$ intersects $\partial K$. Yet then $x/q(x) = x/p(x)$.